# Django Rest Framework group fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm exposing an REST api for legacy application.

I have a Company model class that defines the following fields:

- address_street (required)
- address_street_number (required)
- shipping_address_street (optional)
- shipping_address_street_number (optional)
- billing_address_street (optional)
- ... you got the point

I would like to group all address fields into an Adress serializer in order to have a cleaner structure.
Some thing like:

```
{
  "adress": {"street": "foo", "street_number": "bar"},
  "shipping_address": {"street": "ham", "street_number": "spam"},
  "billing_address": null,
}
```

So far, I can create a *CompanySerializer* from a `rest_framework.serializers.Serializer` and manually build my *Company* objects from this.
It is tedious, but it will work.

But how can I build a `rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer` for my *Company* model, changing the way fields are structured to have my model fields automatically populated by rest framework ?

[DRF nested model serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) seems to only work for relations, not groups of fields.

Am I to build my models instances by hands or is there a way to decouple the representation of a model serializer to my object ?

Answer (score 1):

From `ModelSerializer` [documentation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L847)

```
The process of automatically determining a set of serializer fields
 based on the model fields is reasonably complex
```

You probably should stick to the "tedious" method you mention (you will have to put in some effort if serializer representation and model fields have different structures altogether).

`ModelSerializer` is tightly linked to the model in question, so overriding that behaviour seems to be for little benefit when you can do the same thing using a plain `Serializer` and put object creation under `save`.

Maybe you need to override the `data` property/method on the `Serializer` subclass so that you get a dict that is fit for consumption directly by the model, that might make it less tedious

Answer (score 0):

You can build custom serialiser fields with SerializerMethodField:

```
from rest_framework.fields import SerializerMethodField

class AdressSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    adress = SerializerMethodField()
    shipping_address = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_adress(self, instance):
      return {
          "street": instance.address_street, 
          "street_number": instance.address_street_number
        }

    def get_shipping_address(self, instance):
       // same approach as above
```

If needed to populate the model from the same data representation, the best approach is to override serialiser's `save` method. I don't think there is an "automatic" way of doing it.